# how to echo two colomn SQL data with the difference of the two in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone help with the following code. Im simply trying to display the total number of values between the starting num and ending num. ie: If the start is 200 and end is 205, I need to print 200,201,202,203,204 and 205 on the screen. Please assist with the following code

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die ("Server connection failure!");
$db=mysql_select_db('regional_data',$con) or die ("Couldn't connect the database");
$SQL="SELECT startnum, endnum FROM newchk";
$run=mysql_query($SQL,$con) or die ("SQL Error");
$nor=mysql_num_rows($run);


while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($run))
{
    for($i=$rec['startnum']; $i=$rec['endnum']; $i++)
    {
    echo $i;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `<` in your `for` loop condition.

```
for($i=$rec['startnum']; $i<=$rec['endnum']; $i++)
{
    echo $i;
}
```

***Note:*** the code dose not contain comma in the output, it will produce `200201202203204205` in the screen.

If you want to print comma concentrated string, you could do:

```
echo implode(',', range($rec['startnum'], $rec['endnum']));
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Also xdazz can you tell me how include <br> to print the values vertically on the screen? Many thanks!

Comment: `echo $i . '<br>';` or `echo implode('<br>', range($rec['startnum'], $rec['endnum']));`